# Reading spaces on C

Tags: c, char, scanf

I'm trying to read a serie of characters like the following one in C:

```
   &&&&&&&&\n& & &    &\n& & &&&& &\n
```

(notice that in the beginning there are spaces too).

I'm using a cicle "while" with:

```
scanf("%c",&cvar);
```

because I'm "storing" the characters into an array of structs that i'm using.

However, the program keeps ignoring the first spaces, and only starts storing from the first '&' appearence.

Any tips? Thank you in advance and sorry for my poor english.

Here is part of the code:

```
while(scanf("%c",&lab[i].simb)!=EOF){
    lab[i].x=x;
    lab[i].y=y;
    if(lab[i].simb=='\n'){
        x=0;
        y++;            
    } else x++;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Too broad of a question. Please supply the snippet of code where `scanf` is being used.

Comment: just read the whole line and process each character from the buffer.  Less headaches in the long run.

Comment: Use fgets() and go through the resultant line character by character.

Comment: Give us the code snippet.

Comment: Why you are using `x = 0` in `if`.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `" %c"` (with a leading blank) for the format string?  Using `scanf()` to repeatedly read just a single character is a bit like using a steamroller to crack an egg; it works, but it isn't necessary.  You could be using `getchar()` instead.  You are testing the result from `scanf()`; that is good — well done.  You could always add a `printf("Read: %d (%c)\n", lab[i].simb, lab[i].simb);` to the loop so you see exactly what character values are being read.

Answer (score 0):

[Read this...](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatted-Input-Basics.html#Formatted-Input-Basics)

I'll suggest to use *getline* if you are using *gcc*, but if however you want to read each character use *getc* instead of *scanf*... and sorry for my poor English too...